# How to pass unsaved model to view with decent_exposure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I just recently started using [decent_exposure](https://github.com/voxdolo/decent_exposure) and I run into a problem when I try to display the model validation error messages in the view. Is there a cleaner way of doing this other than using the render method and instance variables to bypass decent_exposure (back to the old ways)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `form_for`, you can pass the exposed resource as the instance argument and then call `f.error_messages`. There's really not much of a difference there. Maybe I missed the point though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As far as I now, the default behavior for the expose method when no block is passed to it is just to return an instance using find_by_id. My problem is that the model object is just newly instantiated and cannot be saved to the database because it fails the validations. And thus, I am having trouble on how to get around this.